# Why addEventListener can accept this as the second parameter?

Tags: javascript

I am watching the source code of some library.

Then, I found addEventListener can accept this as the second parameter.

The key code such as

```
<body>
    <div id='app'></div>
    <script>
        this.onclick=function(){
            console.log('onclick');
        }
        app.addEventListener('click',this);
    </script>
</body>
```

I am so confused about this.

Comment: this explains it pretty well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: What are you confused about exactly?

Comment: The event is attached to `window`, not `app`. No event handler is actually attached to `app` at `app.addEventListener()`

Comment: Right there in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener): `listener`:
This must be **an object implementing the `EventListener` interface**, or a JavaScript function.*

Comment: @Optimae I never see this usage which input `this` as the second parameter in addEventListener API, so I am so confused about this usage.But I seem to understand it because of @Ben Rondeau

Comment: Thank everyone, I understand it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I recommend that @BenRondeau post it as an answer and you can check it as an answer so other people don't need to search in the comments :)